# Omnet++: C++ simple condition

Tags: c++, omnet++, inet

What might be the reason that this condition is not true and else is executed

```
IPassiveQueue *queueModule = nullptr;    
queueModule = nullptr;
    if (queueModule == nullptr) {...}
    else {...}
```

**[edit1]** Based on the answer below I am adding here the reason behind why I am trying to force the condition to be true

The code below is always checking the first condition and executing else. It is in initialize so it doesnt depend on any previous executed class and the queueModule member is set in class definition as protected member

```
class INET_API EtherMACBase : public MACBase
{virtual void initializeQueueModule(); 
IPassiveQueue *queueModule = nullptr;
...}

void EtherMACBase::initializeQueueModule()
{
    queueModule = nullptr;
    if (par("queueModule").stringValue()[0]) {...}

    else {...}

 }
```

While in this case the condition is true although the parameter is set to be the same

```
class INET_API PPP : public MACBase
{
  protected:
    IPassiveQueue *queueModule = nullptr;
    virtual void initialize(int stage) override;
    ...
}

void PPP::initialize(int stage)
{
     queueModule = nullptr;
     if (par("queueModule").stringValue()[0]) {...}

     else {...}
}
```

**[edit2]** [This picture for Debugging asked by Jerzy D.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XAa8Z.png)

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. The error cannot be in just the code bits you've posted.

Comment: probably you forgot to rebuild or deploy fresh binaries which correspond to code.

Comment: Currently there is no reason, I don't think anyone would use C++ if the `else` block could execute here.

Comment: Read about [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). You probably have some UB *elsewhere* (some other code, or even some other thread). Recompile *all your code* with *all warnings & debug info* (e.g. `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g3` if using [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)...). Improve the code till you get no warnings. Then **use the debugger** (`gdb`) notably watchpoints.

Comment: it is in omnet++ so it includes many classes that are inherited from each other. What I am sure of is that using PPP Class  with same condition it works while in EtherMAC Class else is executed. I tried to change the condition to force it to be true as that example above but still is else is executed.

Comment: It would happen if you missed the second '=' in the comparison, so that 'if (queueModule = nullptr) {'. Then it would be an assignment which yields 0/NULL which is false, so the else branch would be executed. But the code you posted here should not result in such a behavior.

Comment: But you should question *your own code*. Generally, libraries have been tested a lot, and have less bugs than your own code.

Comment: @Basile Starynkevitch I read about the undefined behaviour and I can't deny that this might be the reason, but it is not a code that I wrote. All I have done is use class instead of another class that is already given as option. 

I already found that the condition is executed or else is executed by debugging

Comment: @Angew I added the verifiable example as asked

Comment: @nikitoz It is not the only class I change to execute my example and all other changes works normally whenever I change.

Comment: If you are sure that the bug is not yours (and I am not sure of that, because I believe *you have a bug* in *your code*), then please write a small test case exercising the bug and make a bug report to `omnet++`; in all cases your question is off-topic here.

Comment: @Basile Starynkevitch 
Thanks for your help, I don't know if bug means that the code has errors or it works as not expected but in all cases I  started the question very clearly that even with forcing condition to be true it is not still true and wasn't sure if the mistake in the condition. Later I was asked by others to show the verifiable code and this why I edited the question.

In all cases thank you for your time and I will try to ask more about it before reporting it as omnet++ bug.

Comment: I guess that by trying to make a small test case for a bug report, you are very likely to get insight about your own code and find the (*apparently* unrelated) bug in it. Unless you are a very senior developer, I am supposing that `omnet++` has less bugs than your own code (which I don't find very readable).

Comment: Your actual code doesn't seem to contain the test you first posted. Is `par("queueModule").stringValue()[0]` related to the variable and, if it is, how?

Comment: @molbdnilo this condition `par("queueModule").stringValue()[0]`, using EtherMACBase class is false but using PPP is true. Both have the pointer queueModule set the the same toof type IPassiveQueue and pointing at null. Both classes are in the omnet++ I didn't edit anything other than I used EtherMACBase in my example and found that PPP is reacting differently in existing example in omnet++ although both have the same function but result is different at this exact line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is a consequence of different declarations of default queue type for PPP and Ethernet interfaces in `NED` files in `INET`.
Look at these two files: `src/inet/linklayer/ppp/PPPInterface.ned` and `src/inet/linklayer/ethernet/EthernetInterface.ned`. The crucial parts of these files are below.

```
module PPPInterface like IWiredNic
{
    parameters:
        string queueType = default("DropTailQueue"); 
    submodules:
        queue: <queueType> like IOutputQueue if queueType != "" {
        }
        ppp: PPP {
            parameters:
                queueModule = (queueType == "" ? "" : "^.queue");
        }
}
```

---

```
module EthernetInterface like IWiredNic
{
    parameters:
        string queueType = default(""); 
    submodules:
        queue: EtherQoSQueue if queueType != "" {
        }
        mac: <macType> like IEtherMAC {
            parameters:
                queueModule = (queueType == "" ? "" : "^.queue");
        }
}
```

One can notice that `PPPInterface` **has** an assigned default value for `queueType` parameter, and therefore there is a queue submodule as well as parameter `queueModule` is not empty. 
However, `EthernetInterface` does not have a value of `queueType`, so there is no queue submodule, and parameter `queueModule` is an empty string. Reading of `[0]` element of empty string results in 0 (false).

Comment: Thanks for your answer that was helpful, I understood that external queue is seen empty or not seen at all but I didn't know what would be the reason and still don't know why by forcing the condition to be true it was still false. If I have further question in the same topic should I make new question or edit my question again or send it in an answer?

Comment: 1. In which file have you written this condition? Could you show whole method? 2. Yes, you should as a new question.

Comment: I found out I am not allowed to ask new questions because of the negative feedback I got for this question. I can only ask in 2 days from now. "I don't know if there is a solution for that?". The condition I forced it to be true in `MACEtherBase.cc` in initialize as I explained above. I replaced that line `if (par("queueModule").stringValue()[0])` with that line `if (queueModule == nullptr)`.

Comment: I have just added your code in `EtherMACBase`: `void EtherMACBase::initializeQueueModule() { queueModule = nullptr; if (queueModule == nullptr) { /* 1 */} else { /* 2 */ } ... }` I set breakpoints in 1 and 2. I found out, that the condition `(queueModule == nullptr)` was *true*.  So how do you check this condition in your code?

Comment: Try to change back the edit that you have told me about in EthernetInterface.ned and it won't work.  I just rechanged EthernetInterface.ned. Are you also using TrafficConditioner as I do including Classifier 2 queues and PriorityScheduler. Here with debugging else is executed and the condition is false what ever I do.

Comment: No, I don't use TrafficConditioner. Could you describe how you debug your code, and how you determine a state of the condition?

Comment: I added picture in the question with the debugging I did also If I have queueModule =nullptr; none of both if condition or else is executed. By the way after the edits you have advised it works only once in the initialization but the handle message for both interfaces are different. This is what I wanted to send as new question with the codes that I am seeing different.

Comment: I have added the lines `IPassiveQueue *queueModule = nullptr;  if (queueModule == nullptr) { ... } else {...}` in `EtherMACBase.cc` on two machines, and every time the condition *was true*. Try to prepare a clean `INET` source and add test your changes.

Comment: Are you using any priority scheduler in the queueModule to see that request packet is invoked or you are only using debugging in general case?

Comment: I have only used gdb.

Comment: ok I actually did clean and make makefiles then make and did another run and same result although I also used queueModule in EthernetInterface.ned as shown in PPPInterface.ned. I observed it is always else condition is executed as long as I am using TrafficConditioner but If I used queueModule instead it works. I think I am mixing many things and may be working on new question to clear one thing or two would be better. I would really like to thank you for your effort that was really helpful